# Identical **kwargs, but one raising "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence"

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance, new-operator, super

I have a very weird issue with `dict` inheritance. I want to be able to pass custom objects in an instance of the `dict` object, so I made a custom `__new__` method to format these objects so they are compatible with the `dict.__new__` method.

But I am facing a very strange issue. I already read most of the topics talking about this error one stackoverflow, but none are going as far as my code is. Here is my code:

```py
class TextureItem:
    def __init__(self, name: str = "stone") -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'TextureItem({self.name})'

class GlobalPalette(dict[str, TextureItem]):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {}
        print("args and kwargs:", args, kwargs, "\n")
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, list):
                for item in arg:
                    new_kwargs[item.name] = item
            elif isinstance(arg, dict):
                new_kwargs.update(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg, TextureItem):
                new_kwargs[arg.name] = arg
        if kwargs:
            new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
        print("new_kwargs:", new_kwargs, "\n")
        return super().__new__(cls, **new_kwargs)

a = GlobalPalette(stone=TextureItem(), v="OK")
print("a:", a, "\n\n")

b = GlobalPalette([TextureItem()], v="OK")
print("b:", b)
```

This is what I get when running the code:

```
args and kwargs: () {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'}
new_kwargs: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

a: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

args and kwargs: ([TextureItem(stone)],) {'v': 'OK'}
new_kwargs: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/ainbt/t.py", line 28, in <module>
    b = GlobalPalette([TextureItem()], v="OK")
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

The error at the end means I filled an iterable like a `list`, `tuple` or `set`, that contains only "single" objects. Example: `[("a": 1), ("b": 2)]` will be ok, but `["a", "b"]` will raise this error.

This means it comes from the list `[TextureItem()]` in `b = GlobalPalette([TextureItem()], v="OK")`. But why is it detecting it, my own `__new__` should be executed before the `super().__new__`.

Where am I going wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify `__new__`, not `__init__`?

Comment: @matszwecja yes, because if I change in __init__, __new__ of dict won't support certain types of the arguments I am passing by. So I am obligated to edit them before passing in dict's __new__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `__new__` to set dictionary items; that can only be done in the `__init__` method. That is, consider the following example:

```
>>> dict.__new__(dict, v="OK")
{}
```

That is exactly what your code is doing.

I think you want to override `__init__`, not `__new__`, like this:

```
class TextureItem:
    def __init__(self, name: str = "stone") -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'TextureItem({self.name})'

class GlobalPalette(dict[str, TextureItem]):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {}
        print("args and kwargs:", args, kwargs, "\n")
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, list):
                for item in arg:
                    new_kwargs[item.name] = item
            elif isinstance(arg, dict):
                new_kwargs.update(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg, TextureItem):
                new_kwargs[arg.name] = arg
        if kwargs:
            new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
        print("new_kwargs:", new_kwargs, "\n")
        return super().__new__(cls, **new_kwargs)

a = GlobalPalette(stone=TextureItem(), v="OK")
print("a:", a, "\n\n")

b = GlobalPalette([TextureItem()], v="OK")
print("b:", b)
```

Running this results in:

```
args and kwargs: () {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

new_kwargs: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

a: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 


args and kwargs: ([TextureItem(stone)],) {'v': 'OK'} 

new_kwargs: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'} 

b: {'stone': TextureItem(stone), 'v': 'OK'}
```